# How to get list of specific instance and their external IP using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to use `ec2 describe-instances` command to list specific instance that ends with `*-Linux-appsrv` and their public IPs.

I have tried this command which lists all the public IPs.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" --output=text
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "instance that ends with"? Are you referring to the contents of their `Name` tag?

Comment: Yes exactly I'm referring to tag. I want to list all the linux instacens with name tag start with  [name]-linux-appsrv with their external IP.

Answer (score 1):

To limit the output only to instances with a particular Name tag, use `--filters`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=*-linux-appsrv
```

I had this working on a Mac. If you are using Windows, you might need to play around with quotation marks around portions of the command.